# How do I Connect 4 Router with 1 Switches?

Tags: switch, router

Few days ago, I got an challenge from my Senior at my workplace. Here's the representation of the topology that he gave to me :
[image: Topology]

The question is, how I make each pc could ping each other? I tried IGRP and InterVLAN routing and both doesn't work. I even reloading my Router and Switch several times. Thanks in advance.

Here's my current configuration :

```
-Router-A-
Router>en
Router#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#router eigrp 100
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.0.0
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.1.0
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.2.0
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.3.0
Router(config-router)#network 192.168.0.0
Router(config-router)#no auto-summary
Router(config-router)#ex

-Router-B-
Router#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#router eigrp 100
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.0.0
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.1.0
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.2.0
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.3.0
Router(config-router)#network 192.168.0.0
Router(config-router)#no auto-summary
Router(config-router)#ex
Router(config)#

-Router-C-
Router#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#router eigrp 100
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.0.0
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.1.0
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.2.0
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.3.0
Router(config-router)#network 192.168.0.0
Router(config-router)#no auto-summary
Router(config-router)#ex
Router(config)#

-Router-D-
Router#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#router eigrp 100
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.0.0
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.1.0
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.2.0
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.3.0
Router(config-router)#network 192.168.0.0
Router(config-router)#no auto-summary
Router(config-router)#ex
Router(config)#
```

My switch configuration :

```
Switch(config-if)#ex
Switch(config)#int fa0/1
Switch(config-if)#switchport mode access
Switch(config-if)#switchport access vlan1
                                        ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Switch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 1
Switch(config-if)#ex
Switch(config)#int fa0/2
Switch(config-if)#switchport mode access
Switch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 1
Switch(config-if)#ex
Switch(config)#int fa0/3
Switch(config-if)#switchport mode access vlan 1
                                         ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Switch(config-if)#switchport mode access
Switch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 1
Switch(config-if)#ex
Switch(config)#int fa0/4
Switch(config-if)#switchport mode access
Switch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 1
Switch(config-if)#ex
Switch(config)#
```

Comment: You need to add the router and switch configurations.

Comment: I get it. But which configuration? I tried both with IGRP and InterVLAN but doesn't work

Comment: No you misunderstand, you need to edit your question to include the configuration of your switch and routers. You can add the text and format it as code using {} around it.

Comment: Oh, okay. I'm sorry. Brb, updating it.

Comment: Done. Configuration added. Sorry, I'm totally new into CIsco Switches and Router...

Comment: I was going to write an answer that would give you a clean ip routing network. Then I spotted that all 4 PCs have IP addresses from the same subnet. 192.168.0.x/24. This is either a mistake or it is the actual key point of the challenge. Please check with your coworker if it is intentional that all 4 PCs are in 192.168.0.0/24

Comment: Okay, I contacted my coworker, but he's currently busy. He's giving me a clue about using sub-interface each router to get this done. But I'm only able to ping each router. Maybe you could differentiate each all 4 PCs with different subnet ?

Comment: I mean each PC with different subnet, free as you like.

Comment: If the PCs could change IP addresses to be in seperate subnets (for example 192.168.1.10/24, 192.168.2.10/24, 192.168.3.10/24, 192.168.4.10/24), then the solution could be "simple and clean" by enabling routing on the switch (turning it into a L3-switch) with a) 4 VLANs and 4 SVIs (`ìnterface vlan`) or b) routed ports (`no switchport, ip address ...`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Configure CoreSwitch for routing

- turn on ip routing
- no switchport on each port
- assign ip addresses
- enable eigrp asn 1 on each port

Get all routers on EIGRP ASN 1 through their /30 10.10.x.0/30 networks, don't advertise 192.168.0.0 subnets, it will screw up everything.

- assign ip addresses to interfaces that connect to CoreSwitch
- write descriptions
- enable eigrp asn 1 on connections to CoreSwitch and loopbacks, 'network 10.10.x.0 0.0.0.3', 'network 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0'
- Assign each router a loopback, eg RA loopback0 is 1.1.1.1/32, RB is 2.2.2.2/32

Ensure connectivity through 10.10.x.0/30 addresses by pinging routers from routers

- ping all all routers loopbacks from each router to ensure connectivity
- use each routers loopback as the source of the ping with extended ping commands

***loopbacks will be used with nat**

- Address hosts on 192.168.0.0/24 subnets

Gateway IP address on each router's internal interface can be 192.168.0.254/24

- assign gateway IP addresses on each router's internal interface
- assign default gateways on hosts
- ping from each host to their default gateway
- ping default gateway's loopback ensure default gateway is working

Last step and the only tricky part, the NATing
I overloaded NAT for interal->external traffic and set static NATs on each gateway with their loopback as the external interface for connections from the external->internal taffic with respect to each gateway

This way router gig/30 interfaces don't have to be used for static NATing and can still be used for other connections

**a loopback can be created and advertised for each static NAT if more than one host exists on each LAN, not that nice but it works
       eg. 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2...1.1.1.n, 2.2.2.1...2.2.2.n**

[Static NAT and NAT overload](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-address-translation-nat/13772-12.html)

**Do the overload first and you can check it by pinging the CoreSwitch's interface from the respective host, then do static NAT and ping from the CoreSwitch to each host**

Overload:

```
RA(config)# interface gi0/2
RA(config-if)# ip nat inside
RA(config)# interface gi0/1
RA(config-if)# ip nat outside
RA(config)# access-list 1 permit 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255  #Will match and 192.168.0.0/24 address
RA(config)# ip nat inside source list 1 interface gi0/1 
#Any matched address will be translated to gi0/1's external interface address solving the problem of 192.168.0.0/24 being non-routable
```

**Ping CoreSwitch from each Host to ensure this is working properly**

[Static](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/long-reach-ethernet-lre-digital-subscriber-line-xdsl/asymmetric-digital-subscriber-line-adsl/12905-827spat.html):

```
RA(config)# int loopback0
RA(config-if)ip nat outside
RA(config)# ip nat inside source static 192.168.0.1 1.1.1.1
        #you will need to change 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.2..192.168.0.4 for each router
```

The proof is in the translation because connectivity to the loopbacks was already proven.

After a ping from PC1 off of RA:

```
RC#show ip nat tran
Pro Inside global      Inside local       Outside local      Outside global
icmp 3.3.3.3:1415      192.168.0.3:1415   2.2.2.2:1415       2.2.2.2:1415
--- 3.3.3.3            192.168.0.3        ---                ---
```

All hosts should have connectivity to all other hosts through static translation through each routers loopbacks to the desired internal host and overloading of each routers external interface for internal connections going out.

The relevant configuration for Router RA ends up looking like this:

```
RA#show run
Building configuration...

hostname RA
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description to CoreSwitch
 ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex full
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 description to PC1
 ip address 192.168.0.254 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex full
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
!
!
router eigrp 1
 network 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0
 network 10.10.1.0 0.0.0.3
!
ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/1 overload
ip nat inside source static 192.168.0.1 1.1.1.1
!
access-list 1 permit 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
!
end
```

After a ping from PC1 to 2.2.2.2
[image]
[image]

And from PC0 behind RB to 10.10.2.2 on the CoreSwitch:
[image]

Comment: Can I use FastEthernet instead GigabitEthernet?

Comment: Yes FastE and GigE differ mainly at the physical layer and will have no effect on an implementation like this

Comment: When I checked with 'show ip nat tran', the Outside Global show IP Addresses from 10.10.x.0/30 network instead the IP from loopback. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: I think what you're seeing should be the case on the host router that you are pinging out from. The router you are pinging the loopback on to reach the host behind it should have the loopback as the outside global.

Comment: I was wrong, I tested more and included the results of my NAT translations in my answer. The addresses are the same in the translations no matter which direction the traffic is going through the router if the loopbacks are being pinged.

Comment: But results like you got would be the case when pinging the CoreSwitch from a host, so what you're seeing is right

Comment: After I configuring the loopback's NAT, I'm not able to ping anymore from PC to CoreSwitch. I think NAT from ge0/1 clash with the loopback, maybe? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Plus, I still didn't able to ping each PC after configuring the NAT for loopback. Is there anything missed step?

Comment: If you have a chance, make a video tutorial about this please. I'm stuck on above steps.

Comment: It sounds like NAT overloading is working. Make sure the static addresses are correct `ip nat inside source static 192.168.0.2 2.2.2.2...192.168.0.4 4.4.4.4` and all interfaces are assigned correctly. If you can ping between RA to RB to RC to RD's Gi0/1 interfaces in the 10.10.x.0 networks then the problem could be with the default route on the host. Try to find exactly where the packet is being dropped by starting at nearby devices and extending Core->RA, then RA-RB, Core->RA(loopback), RA->RB(loopback) and so on, every time there is traffic to the loopback check to make sure there's NATTing

Comment: `debug ip nat translations` is a helpful easy-to-read command to see what is being translated

Comment: I double-checked again with 'show ip nat tran' command. The Outside local and outside global aren't showing any IP addresses. It should be the neighbor router loopback right?

Comment: And I can't ping from Core->each Router loopback. I absolutely had followed all of your above steps.

Comment: Anyway, here's my router configuration https://pastebin.com/0h5JbFzd

Answer (score 6):

There are two - odd - challenges here.

1. The routers connected to the central switch on a single(!) VLAN have incompatible interface addresses, ie. the each router interface resides in a separate IP network, so they can't talk to each other. You either need to consolidate the inward-facing interface addresses or use secondary addresses that are compatible with each other.
2. The PCs on the routers' far ends all use IP addresses from the same IP network 192.168.0.0/24. When they try to communicate they will not use a router/gateway but try to use their layer-2 connection directly, ie. ARP the destination and send a frame directly.

The problem in 2. can be overcome by either bypassing the routers completely and
use a common VLAN between the PCs - preferred solution

or

Each router needs to source/destination NAT the PCs in a wild scheme: e.g. PC0 could address PC1 as 192.168.**129**.1 which is routed to Router 4 (which NATs the source address to 192.168.**128**.2), across the central switch to Router 5 (which NATs the destination address to 192.168.**0**.1) - this is the mad hatter solution. Obviously, each PC needs to use its router as default gateway and each router needs to know the routes to the (NATed) PC networks.

Answer (score -1):

```
- router eigrp 100
network 10.10.0.0 0.0.0.3 
- IP address /Mask on the router interfaces
- default route
- PC configuration
```

Comment: Can you explain little bit more clear about that default route?

Comment: My eng is not very good. So i'm not sure it will be very "clear" in explanation :D

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Fa0/0 (exit interface)